# Won't read or play CD/DVD?

Tags: dvd, cd

I have an emachine W3105. 
AMD Sempron 3100+ 1.8 GHz processor
512 MB RAM
100 GB hard drive
DVD±RW DL drive

I replace windows XP OS with Ubuntu 12.04 and it won't detect the DVD±RW DL drive. I ran sudo `lshw -C disk` and this what I get.

```
PCI (sysfs)  
  *-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: HDS728080PLAT20
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: PF2O
       serial: PFD202S4SM9LHJ 
       size: 76GiB (82GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=000adb4f
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD reader
       product: RW/DVD GCC-4482B
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: 1.00
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-disk:0
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
  *-disk:1
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.1
       bus info: scsi@4:0.0.1
       logical name: /dev/sdc
  *-disk:2
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.2
       bus info: scsi@4:0.0.2
       logical name: /dev/sdd
  *-disk:3
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.3
       bus info: scsi@4:0.0.3
       logical name: /dev/sde
```

It look to me that Ubuntu OS detect the DVD drive. Does this mean I have to install the propriety drivers for AMD? I also tried the `mount` command and I get this

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/humberto/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=humberto)
```

I tried this command `lspci -vvnn | grep GA` and I get this,

```
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping+ SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: VIA Technologies, Inc. K8M800/K8N800/K8N800A [S3 UniChrome Pro] [1106:3108] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
```

This is where I get stuck. I just want to be able to read CD and DVD in the drive? Can anyone help. THANK YOU

Comment: It detects the drive as it is listed right there in your output.  Do you mean it does not detect that there is a disc loaded into the drive?  Can you still boot from the install cd?

Comment: Yes it does not detect the disc drive. When I try VLC this is the error I get Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "/dev/dvd".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///dev/dvd'. Check the log for details.

Comment: What about a regular data CD-ROM?

Comment: Yes it read a CD-ROM. I've going through other question on ubuntu. Then my problem is DVD player.

Comment: Is this an internal or external dvd-drive? I had a similar issue with an external drive and it turned out that it wasn't getting enough power because of a usb hub I was using. It would detect since it was connected, but not function because of the lack of power.

Comment: What about a DVD-ROM ( data disc )?  Is the problem just with the video player?  If you took the posted `lshw` with a DVD in the drive, then the status=nodisc indicates the drive says it has no medium, so it would be a hardware problem.  If CDs work but DVDs don't, then the DVD laser has burnt out ( CDs use a different laser ).